# Kendo datasource requestEnd event parameter has no type

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have a kendo grid where I want to execute some code after the datasource syncs. In my datasource, I have the `requestEnd` event defined as:

```
requestEnd: function(e) {
    console.log(e);

    // More code...
}
```

On initial page load, the event fires after `read` and I see the logged object as:

[image: requestEnd object after a read operation]

However, later on when I call a create / update via `grid.dataSource.sync()` the event object is logged, but is missing the `type` property:

[image: create / update operations lack the <code>type</code> property]

Why does the event parameter in `requestEnd` look good in read operations, but is missing data in create / update operations? I've also tried using the `sync` event, but when I include that in my datasource, it doesn't seem to ever get hit at all.

Comment: Show your datasource code. What are you returning back after the create/update? For example `return Json(new[] { myViewModel }.AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));` Also make sure a DataSource error handler is not being hit.

Comment: @SteveGreene In the controller? nothing. it just serializes the data into a DB and then gives a 200 or 500 depending on what happens

Comment: can you able to duplicate the case in dojo? i think the problem is in the transport options of the grid datasource